# Dependency configuration process in Visual Studio never completes for Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to add an Azure SQL Server Database as a connected service in Visual Studio Professional 2019 (16.8.5).  I go through the Connect Services wizard for adding a Service Dependency and I select my db and Azure Key Vault, and it is prepared to make the following changes:

[image]

However, the last dialog gets stuck while verifying access to my key vault.  The "Configuring..." spinner churns for awhile, then goes away and nothing happens.

[image]

I see nothing in the Output window.  Why is this happening, how can I get it to complete, and where are the log files that may shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: I eventually found the cause - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same process successfully through Azure CLI commands and was able to discover an exception when calling CreateHostBuilder during app startup that shed more light on what caused the problem in Visual Studio:

> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.KeyVaultReferenceException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Key vault error. ErrorCode:, Key:TestApp:Settings:KeyVaultMessage, Label:, Etag:H8dquOypXBlg5BTPF035GP4VpS1, SecretIdentifier:https://{SNIP}.vault.azure.net/secrets/Message
> Source=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultKeyValueAdapter.d__3.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.d__26.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.d__25.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.d__20.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.AzureAppConfigurationProvider.Load()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at ASP.NET_Core_101.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\elega\Source\Repos\ASP.NET-Core-101\ASP.NET Core 101\Program.cs:line 17

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

> [External Code]
> Inner Exception 1:
> RequestFailedException: Service request failed.
> Status: 403 (Forbidden)
> Content:
> {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Access denied to first party service.\r\nCaller: name=from-infra;tid=f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a;appid=872cd9fa-d31f-45e0-9eab-6e460a02d1f1;iss=https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/\r\nVault: {SNIP}Vault;location=northcentralus","innererror":{"code":"AccessDenied"}}}

The issue was because the account I was logged into Visual Studio with for my Azure subscription is associated with a MSA, and when I switch to a M365 account in VS that has global admin privileges in that same subscription, the issue went away.  The MSA account is the "first party service" referenced in the call stack error.

More details can be found in the issue I posted here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/70955